# How to access WebHost configuration inside a service?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm configuring a simple `TestServer` like that:

```
var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .AddInMemoryCollection(new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        { "qwe1","zzzzzzzzz"}
    })
    .Build();
var webHostBuilder = new WebHostBuilder()
    .UseConfiguration(config)
    .UseStartup<Startup>();
_server = new TestServer(webHostBuilder);
```

But I can't find `qwe1` configuration in `Startup`. Here's a constructor:

```
public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", true, true)
        .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", true)
        .AddEnvironmentVariables();
    _configuration = builder.Build();
    var q = _configuration["qwe1"]; // q is null
}
```

Not surprising, but I did't found anything in `IHostingEnvironment` and extension methods like `AddHostConfiguration()`. So what is the right way to inject config from host initialization to `Startup` class?

Comment: You're creating a new configuration inside Startup, you must use env.Configuration if you want to retrieve the one set with UseConfiguration.

Comment: @Gusman But where's this `env.Configuration`, I was looking for something like that, but can't find

Comment: What's is the reason you want to add a config value to memory config used by TestServer, and read that value in your actual Startup class?

Comment: @Ignas I need to be able to turn off or reconfigure some features of the tested pipeline (logging, authorization). I don't want this configuration to be modifiable in production.